# Can be certain items in an array be compared for something to be true - C#

Tags: c#, .net

i have been having trouble getting this code to work is there something wrong with it or am i just doing it wrong

```
string a = teams[1];
string b = wins[1];
int numWins = 0;
while (o < wins.Length)
{                    
    if (a != b)
    {
        numWins++;
    }
    o++;                       
}

numOfWinsLabel.Text = numWins.ToString();
```

it is adding to the counter when both of them are equal in the txt files that i have set

Can someone plz help me?

Comment: It would be helpful if you more clearly explained what your intended result is, and what the current output of the program is.

Comment: @Sam he wants the counter to increment when the team is the winner

Comment: For one o is not declared

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want to walk through the arrays, and you seem to try to use the `o` variable to point to each element. But you're not "telling" the arrays to actually use the `o` variable.

What happens in that case is that the variables get assigned the values of index 1 and they never change. It's also worth noting that arrays usually start at index 0.

Try the following:

```
int numWins = 0;
for (int o = 0; o < wins.Length; o++)
{                    
    string a = teams[o];
    string b = wins[o];

    if (a != b)
    {
        numWins++;
    }                     
}

numOfWinsLabel.Text = numWins.ToString();
```

This of course also assumes that the `teams` has at least as much elements as the `wins` array, or you'll get an exception.

I've changed the `while` to a `for` as it's more suitable for situations where you already know the number of times you want to loop.

Comment: Excellently explained!

Comment: In this case `numWins` should be an array.  Otherwise you are incrementing the counter any time any team wins.  So it will always end up equaling wins.Length

Comment: @SamHazleton I don't know what the arrays contain, and frankly I don't understand what you think the arrays contain.